# Collect system and hardware informations of remote (apache and tomcat) servers from java code

Tags: java

I look for a solution to get hardware information about remote servers using java code

Comment: How is this related to software testing?

Comment: TO test the actual status od the server:CPU+RAM+DISK USAGE...

Answer (score 1):

Server monitoring is more a operational task then testing, have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers most server monitoring tools have an API that can be used to get the info from a programming language.

I would have a look at the open-source [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) it has Java API plugins: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/APIs/Java

Comment: There are also times when diagnosing a bug requires knowing whether a system is using all the CPU, or using too much memory, etc.  Ideally, a tester would take advantage of whatever monitoring technology the production servers use, because the people in charge of the production servers probably know more about monitoring than you do.

Comment: @user246 Another usage might be when benchmarking comparing during load-tests, but the OP is a bit vague on his goals :)